# Dynamic resistance of a p-n junction diode

Tags: diodes, pn-junction

The slope of the graph between current and voltage in a p-n junction diode, under both forward bias and under reverse bias, varies a lot on varying the voltage. Hence, given the graph, how do we decide which two points to take to calculate ΔV and ΔI in order to find \$r=ΔV/ΔI\$?

Comment: You have to find the working point of the circuit. If you know your load will be around 1A, assume 1A for I.

Comment: A close approximation for forward current vs forward voltage is that I(f) increases by a factor of 10 for each extra 60mV forward voltage.

Comment: @PeterSmith  wouldn't that apply to small signal diodes only?

Comment: Maybe the OP's question should read, how do I measure tangent on any curve?

Answer (score 1):

> how do we decide which two points to take to calculate ΔV and ΔI

[image]

Any two points on the black line marked linear approximation will do. For instance you could take 0.7 volts, 0.015 amps and 0.75 volts, 0.06 amps.

\$\Delta V\$ is 50 mV and \$\Delta I\$ is 45 mA hence R is about 1.1 ohms. Any two points would give the same answer.

Comment: In reverse bias also we have to do the same thing right, after the breakdown voltage?

Comment: A tangent to the slope conveniently gives you points that can be used in forward or reverse bias.

Comment: Any two points would give the same answer ?? within what error tolerance ? +/-1 octave?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 "Any two points on the black line marked linear approximation" will do. Tolerance is only as good as you can draw a tangent to the curve.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard for incremental resistance measurements for general purpose diodes and LEDs, however there are industry standards for Zeners. So it is relevant to understand these methods.

There is  some value  in specifying the knee of the curve where the linear resistance begins to dominate the curve or looks like a **k**nee shape on the curve. In this case it is called \$Z_{ZK}\$ and it for a 500mW Zener is measured at \$I_{ZK}\$ **= 0.25mA.**

- **Analogy:** just like the RdsOn at Vgs(th) has a high resistance at some standard low conduction current , when used as a switch you must use >250% of this Vgs threshold. So too, you would operate a diode when its conduction resistance is low at a much higher current.

Thus they also define the standard Zener **T**hreshold resistance at a standard threshold current that results in **+/-15% tolerance** on the zener voltage. This is called \$Z_{ZT}  @ I_{ZT} \$

- Note that the power levels at this current are much less than the rated Power Dissipation.  LED's are often specified for **f**orward voltage at rated Pd and  this is why they can have +/-50% tolerance for \$V_F\$

[image]

> **how do we decide which two points to take?**

Best guess: (you choose) Because  it depends on how the result is used.

- if you want to determine compare suppliers  for the lowest resistance for a fixed power level, then choose that fixed power level and measure that slope.
- OR choose the middle of the intended operating range
- OR compare various power levels at rated power current levels
- or choose 10% of the rated current and compare similar parts.

I tried all of these methods and more and found that the best estimate of R { or ESR } for diodes and LEDs is to look up the rated package power rating and let **ESR = k/Pd for k=1** in most cases and with very efficient thermal high power packages k reduces to 0.5 with a tolerance still of 50% at rated power just like Vf tolerances at the rated current levels.

See how ESR changes in Red below along the curve. This is not even counting the 50% tolerance at rated power, but is useful for predicting performance.
[image]

Comment: The keen observer will see this example of the VI curve in Blue and power in Yellow and ESR in Red and see that ESR~2 Ohms for a device rated for 0.5W but only operating at half max power could be interpreted with my formula with a k<1 which is a very good thermal design.